# Upgrade Symfony from 3.3.2 to 3.4 / Twig incompatibility

Tags: symfony, twig, composer-php

I do not know if I'm missing something obvious. So, I am trying to update Symfony from 3.3.2 to 3.4. I checked the problems with

```
php composer.phar update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies
```

I got the following feedback:

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.5.0
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.8
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.7
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.6
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.5
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.4
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.35.4
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.35.3
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.35.2
- Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v1.34.2, required as ^1.0||^2.0) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.34.2].
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.35.1
- symfony/symfony v3.4.0 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.1 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.10 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.11 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.12 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.13 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.14 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.15 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.16 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.17 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.2 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.3 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.4 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.5 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.6 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.7 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.8 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- symfony/symfony v3.4.9 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0].
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.35.0
- Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9]
```

What I do not understand is the contradiction between the fact that I'd have to install a new version of twig but at the same time that I should not. I checked the Documentation of Symfony but found nothing. Anyway I tried updating with various versions of twig without success.
I could still follow this solution but I fear I mess up my code.

[How to properly update Symfony3.3 to Symfony4.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133458/how-to-properly-update-symfony3-3-to-symfony4-x)

**EDIT 1**

I saw in another forum a solution. I tried it so I deleted the composer.lock and the vendor directory. Now the packages are downloaded anew but during the process I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                           
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  
In ParameterBag.php line 102:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "mailer_port". Did you mean this: "mailer_host"?`
```

**EDIT 2**

Old Composer

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.1.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.2",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.1"
```

New composer

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.1.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "~3.4",
    "twig/twig": "~1.35|~2.44"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "3.3.2"
```

Does anyone have an idea what should be done ?

Comment: `symfony/symfony v3.4.0 requires twig/twig ^1.35|^2.4.4` -> do you have twig 1.35 or 2.4.4 and above? Looks like you're still targeting Symfony 3 code ... maybe update your composer.json file to reflect the new changes

Comment: I have twig 1.35.4 currently installed. If I update anyway with php composer.phar update it gives me the error of my EDIT1 in the post.

Comment: but have you tried manually updating composer json?

Comment: If by manually changing you mean modifying the require object in composer.json I did it to fit the previous request of composer until I got stuck in this loop. I uploaded my old and new composer in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write back `"twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"`, and then change `"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2"` to `"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0"`, that's the only differences I can see between your composer.json and the composer.json of a new Symfony 3.4.16 project.

Comment: Then I get the following error along the one concerning twig.  `The requested package sensio/framework-extra-bundle (installed at v3.0.26, required as ^5.0.0) is satisfiable by sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.26] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability`.  Is it possible that something is missing because I copied the whole website folder to another computer also running LAMP to try the update without messing the original ?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I did not find the answer. Instead I installed a new Symfony 3.4 and copied my project in it. I had to do a few changes (just with twig which was the problem for updating) but it works now. Anyway I'm still interested to know what was the error if anyone has an idea.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your last question... I'm glad you could make it work!